# Hide layout of elementList after click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-studio

I have created a listView where there are 2 Item_separator and multiple item_element.
I want to hide a part of my item_element after click on the minus's button element of my Item_separator (the element encircled in red), like this:
[image]

This is my item element layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/Item_Layout_Container">
    <!-- Icon -->

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Item_Layout_Icon"
            android:layout_width="81dp"
            android:layout_height="79dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/green_circle">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_symbol"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Title -->
    <TextView
        style="@style/AppTheme.Text.Large"
        android:id="@+id/Item_Layout_Title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Item_Layout_Icon"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Item_Layout_Icon"
        android:text="Title"
       />
    <!-- Description -->
    <TextView
        style="@style/AppTheme.Text.Medium"
        android:id="@+id/Item_Layout_Description"
        android:layout_below="@id/Item_Layout_Title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="description"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Item_Layout_Icon"
        />

  <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="15.30"
        android:id="@+id/Item_Layout_Time"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Item_Layout_Icon"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Item_Layout_Icon"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Item_Layout_Icon"
        android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And on my activity, I have used an Adapter to set my element, I have try to did this but It doesn't work:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        switch (type) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);
                holder.Title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Item_Layout_Title);
                holder.Description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Item_Layout_Description);
                holder.Time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Item_Layout_Time);
                holder.Icon = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Item_Layout_Icon);
                holder.IconState = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_symbol);    
                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.separator, null);
                holder.Title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                holder.ButtonHide = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnminus)
                break;
        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    switch (type) {
        case TYPE_ITEM:
            holder.Title.setText(mData.get(position).title);
            holder.Description.setText(mData.get(position).description);
            holder.Time.setText(mData.get(position).time);
            holder.Icon.setBackgroundResource(mData.get(position).iconLayout);
            holder.IconState.setImageResource(mData.get(position).iconImage);
            holder.Icon.setTag(mData.get(position).iconLayout);
            holder.Icon.setOnClickListener(myImageClickListener);
            break;
        case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
            holder.Title.setText(mData.get(position).title);
            textTag = mData.get(position).title;
            holder.ButtonHide.setOnClickListener(hideElement);
            break;
    }

    return convertView;
}

public View.OnClickListener hideElement = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
};
```

This is a test but It doesn't work; How can I hide the element after the second item_separator? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use `v.setVisibility(View.GONE);` and you should GONE container with this block. Something like this: `public View.OnClickListener hideElement = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        holder.Description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
};`
And you can do something like this:

```
private class OnHideElementClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView mDescriptionBlockText;

        public OnHideElementClickListener(TextView descriptionBlock) {
            mDescriptionBlockText = descriptionBlock;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDescriptionBlockText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

And use it: `holder.Icon.setOnClickListener(new OnHideElementClickListener());`

Comment: Thank you @Alex Koblov but It doesn't work. I have found how to do it. The solution is to add all of my listitem on an list of Relative layout, and after I press on my textarea of my ITem_separator I have to set visibility GONE of my item that are after the item separator (position+1)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
 v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

instead of

```
v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

As per my suggestion if you would like to hide views, it is better to use LinearLayout than RelativeLayout

Comment: ok it works, but how I can hide the element after the itemseparator?